# angularjs controller does not work after jquery load

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

Hi guys I have a problem, I have a two part site:

- one is the main part, where i don't use angularJS (and I prefer to not use it in this part), the task of this part is to load an external html (the second part of the site) into a div throug the jquery 'load' function.
- the second part uses angularJS, I noticed that if I don't use controllers the angular code runs while if I add controllers the angular stop to runs.

I already saw the $compile function but I want to find a solution without putting angularJS on the first part, If it is possible, because it sounds strange that with ng-init angular works while with ng-controller doesn't work...

The code that loads into a div [first part]:

```
$('.AVcontent').load('./code.html', {c:c,p:p}, function(r,status,x)
{
    if (status == 'error')
        $(".AVcontent").html("error");
});
```

The code that works [second part]:

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="title = 'Hello';">{{title}}</div>
```

The code that doesn't work [second part]:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope)
    {
        $scope.firstName= "John";
        $scope.lastName= "Doe";
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br />
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
```

does anybody knows how to fix this?
thanks.

**---EDIT:**
To better understand I don't have two ng-app in the same time:

- In the firstpart.html I have the load code, this remains over time forever and ever.
- In the secondpart.html first I try the first code where I haven't controllers, but i use ng-init: With this second part all works fine.
- Now I replace the secondpart.html with the second code that I gave above and I see that nothing works any more.

Comment: you can not have multiple ng-app on single page then you need to bootstrap you app inside page

Comment: read edit thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Angular will compile the first app he finds ,,,
so you will need to manually bootstrap the other app like this
angular.bootstrap("#divId",["myApp"]);